# Question on combination of >>, << operators & cin and cout objects

Tags: c++, whitespace, iostream, cout, cin

```
char word[10];
int n=5;
while(n--)
{
  cin>>word;
  cout<<n<<" "<<word<<" ";
}
```

Output:

```
ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO
4 ABC 3 DEF 2 GHI 1 JKL 0 MNO
```

Now, my question is what happens when input buffer encounters a blankspace(' ')? It is seen that n is being decremented after every white space but the cout << word does not display anything on screen.

I am confused as i think that the output should be displayed as soon as one word is input. Eg.

```
 ABC 4 ABC DEF 3 DEF GHI 2 GHI JKL 1 JKL MNO 0 MNO
```

Comment: It doesn't read them until you press Enter, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question, but if I'm reading you right: The stream extraction operator reads until it encounters whitespace, and then consumes the whitespace. You don't get a new word consisting of just the whitespace characters.

---

A few minutes later: I went back and re-read again, and now I think I understand what you're asking: the two streams are not synchronized, so the input and output can't be interleaved in the way you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

cin read strings separated by space but space are discarded in the process

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
cout << flush;
```

Or

```
cout << endl;
```

(inside the while)